# Large number conversion decimal to binary in mysql

Tags: mysql, binary, hex, type-conversion, decimal

Below is the converted values in different bases ie Hexadecimal, Decimal, Binary.

```
HexaDecimal   - 33161fa59009c58000006198               
Decimal       - 15810481316372905437683540376           
Binary        - 1100110001011000011111101001011001000000001001110001011000000000000000000000000110000110011000
```

This one i have achieved correctly in Java. But for project i need to do this kind conversion in MySQL. I found out about Conv() http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_conv function which seems work for small no but not for big one sas given above.

Kindly help me if there is any work around for to get these desired results.

Regards,
 Amit